# Not being able to configure bodyParser limit from http.js file, hence getting 413 http error

Tags: node.js, sails.js, body-parser, skipper

As suggested in the documentation here: https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/configuration/sails-config-http#?configuring-skipper, I did uncomment the configuration as follows,

```
module.exports.http = {

    middleware: {

        order: [
           'cookieParser',
           'session',
           'bodyParser',
           'compress',
           'poweredBy',
           'router',
           'www',
           'favicon',
         ],

        bodyParser: (function _configureBodyParser(){
           var skipper = require('skipper');

           var middlewareFn = skipper(
             {
               strict: true,
               limit: '50mb'
             });

           return middlewareFn;
        })(),
    },

};
```

Even after this, I am not being able to upload files which are more than 1 MB.

Skipper Version being used: "sails": "^1.0.2"

Sails version being used: "skipper": "^0.8.7"

Answer (score 1):

Edit file `config/http.js` and uncomment skipper section. Add the limit option.

```
    bodyParser: (function _configureBodyParser(){
      var skipper = require('skipper');
      var middlewareFn = skipper({strict: true, limit: '5mb'});
      return middlewareFn;
    })(),
```